# Can hook +[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:] but calling %orig gives "unrecognized selector"

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, theos

This is baffling me. I have hooked class methods on `NSURLConnection` with no problems but I am stuck with `+[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:]`.

I even tried logging all the class methods with `class_copyMethodList (object_getClass([NSURLSession class]), &count);` and the class method is actually there:

`sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:
initialize`

And the weird thing is the hook does get called so I think we got it right. Calling `%orig()` and just passing the parameters down yields:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1919932b8'`

Here's the hook:

```
+ (NSURLSession *)sessionWithConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration
                                  delegate:(id<NSURLSessionDelegate>)delegate
                             delegateQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
{

    NSURLSession *origResult = %orig(configuration, delegate, queue);

    return origResult;
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Setup details:
[rpetrich's Theos](https://github.com/rpetrich/theos)
Mac OS X 10.9.5
iPad Air 1
iOS 7.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is related to [NSURLSession being a class cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751322/how-to-hook-nsurlsession-methods-with-theos). While the code in OP successfully hooked the class method, `%orig` needs to call on the real class name. So to make it work, this hook has to be placed under `%hook __NSCFURLSession`. The real class name might be different for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
+ (NSURLSession *) sessionWithConfiguration: (NSURLSessionConfiguration *) configuration delegate: (id) delegate delegateQueue: (NSOperationQueue *) queue
{
     NSURLSession *  session  = [ NSURLSession  SessionWithConfiguration : Configuraion  
                            delegate : self 
                       DelegateQueue : nil ];
}
```

delegateQueue Specifies the NSOperationQueue. if your code requires delegateQueue instead of nil you should declare queue.

Comment: Problems:

1. With the case used, `SessionWithConfiguration` `DelegateQueue`, this does not compile because this method is not anywhere or is it supposed to be in another header?

2. If you meant `sessionWithConfiguration` `delegateQueue`. It will end up in a call that is forever recursive because it just calls itself.

3. self cannot be used in a class method, only in an instance method.

Comment: just go through this link http://qiita.com/aKentaKoyama/items/96a979ab3a140e7b39ec