# How to hook NSURLSession methods with theos?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, nsurlsession, theos, logos

I created a tweak project using [rpetrich's theos](https://github.com/rpetrich/theos) and wanted to hook NSURLSession methods but the hooks don't seem to get invoked? Why? This is my Tweak.xm code:

```
%hook NSURLSession

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"testhook dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:");
    return %orig(request, completionHandler);
}

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"testhook dataTaskWithRequest");
    return %orig(request);
}

%end

%hook NSMutableURLRequest

+ (id)requestWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    NSLog(@"testhook NSMutableURLRequest");
    return %orig(URL);
}

%end
```

I added the `NSMutableURLRequest` hook to make sure that the file and the whole tweak was being loaded. I can verify that it does hook `requestWithURL:` but not any of the NSURLSession methods. I am testing against the code from [NSURLSessionExample](http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/).

What's missing here? Has anybody successfully hooked NSURLSession?

Comment: What is the filter for this tweak? Also: the syntax you are using for hooks is Logos, not Theos, so you ought to label questions with that instead of Theos.

Comment: @AehmloLxaitn I used `{ Filter = { Bundles = ( "com.ravi.NSURLSessionExample" ); }; }` which is the bundle ID of the test app. The `NSMutableRequest` hook worked so I guess I got the filter right? I added `logos` tag. I put `theos` anyway since `logos` is a subcomponent of `theos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLSession` is a class cluster, and you are hooking the toplevel class that contains no (or scarce little) code.

You should investigate the subclasses of `NSURLSession`—potentially by logging the real class of an `NSURLSession` object in-situ. In my limited testing, I received an object whose class was truly named `__NSURLSessionLocal`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I will apply this in-situ inspection on the next classes I encounter that I can't hook. On my end it's `__NSCFURLSession`. It's gonna be tricky trying to guess all possible subclass names.

Comment: I have another question related to this. The hook was successful on the class cluster but it failed in calling `%orig` but after putting the hook in the real class name, it worked flawlessly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602286/can-hook-nsurlsession-sessionwithconfigurationdelegatedelegatequeue-but-ca